# Select highest date if not zero

Tags: mysql, sql

I have the following table:

---

**Mails**

- id (int 11 auto increment)
- user_id (int 11)
- subject (varchar 255)
- body (text)
- deleted (datetime)

---

By default the `deleted` column holds the value `0000-00-00 00:00:00` When something gets deleted the `deleted` column will be set to the delete date. e.g.: `2017-08-14 09:37:13`

Now I want to query this table and get either the `user_id` record where `deleted` = `0000-00-00 00:00:00` or the most recent `deleted` value if there is no user record where `deleted` = `0000-00-00 00:00:00`

Comment: If you have zero dates in your database your data is full of junk you need to clean up. Those should be `NULL` if they're not supposed to be assigned. Don't use "magical numbers" for these purposes, it'll hide bugs in your code.

Comment: Legacy databases. You probably know the feel

Comment: I'm probably missing the problem here. Can't you just sort by deleted (descending) and pick the first value? Could you write an example query, show that result and explain what you don't want in that result?

Comment: @Niklas We want to show either the current active record for the user, or the most recently deleted

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can sort a specific value on top with a case:

```
select  user_id
from    YourTable
order by
        case
        when deleted = '0000-00-00 00:00:00' then '9999-12-31 23:59:59'
        else deleted
        end desc
limit   1
```

Where `'9999-12-31 23:59:59'` is the [maximum value of a datetime](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/datetime.html).

For multiple users, you could look up the maximum with a join:

```
select  *
from    Mails m1
join    (
        select  user_id
        ,       max(
                case
                when deleted = '0000-00-00 00:00:00' then '9999-12-31 23:59:59'
                else deleted
                end) max_deleted
        from    Mails
        group by
                user_ud
        ) m2
on      m1.user_id = m2.user_id
        and case
            when m1.deleted = '0000-00-00 00:00:00' then '9999-12-31 23:59:59'
            else m1.deleted
            end = m2.max_deleted
```

Comment: With the limit 1 it works yeah. Do you know a way to get it to work for multiple user_id records?

Answer (score 0):

Making a slight amendment to Andomar's answer to remove the limit you could try something like:

```
SELECT  user_id
FROM    YourTable
WHERE
        case
        when deleted = '0000-00-00 00:00:00' then 'true'
        else deleted then 'true'
        end desc = 'true'
```

As Case statements run sequentially this would try and return true for the filter in the WHERE clause if the deleted date is '0000-00-00 00:00:00' and if this holds false it will move to the next case which always holds try and passes the filter.

Not the prettiest though.